# Android databinding tests fails in Module NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, data-binding, android-databinding

I could not able to run the local unit tests in Module which is using android Data binding library.

First let me tell about the project structure how its configured.

```
project
      | app
           -MainLauncherActivity
      | myLibrary
            -CommonModuleActivity
```

I have created  a new project, after that have added a new module "myLibrary".

the main "app" depends on "myLibrary" module. I have added one activity in "myLibrary" it supports databinding. I called module specific activity from main "app" activity on button click in it. it just works, could able to run the app.

But, Getting the below errors when i add a test case for the Module Activity.

AndroidStudio : 2.3

```
Gradle build tools version 2.3.0 -->
Error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/databinding/DataBinderMapper


Gradle build tools version 2.2.3 -->
Error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/databinding/ViewDataBinding
```

[PROJECT IDE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se1oW.png)

project root gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

below is "app" build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bindingtest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':mylibrary')
}
```

below myLibrary build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
}
```

LibraryActivity:

```
public class MyLibraryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMyLibraryBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_my_library);
        //set data to binding
    }
}
```

Corresponding test case can be found in the attached screenshot.

Could some one tell me what am i doing wrong here to get it tested.

APP IS WORKING FINE, ONLY UNIT-TESTS ARE FAILING!!!

Comment: m still seeking for the solution :(

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, Any one  else is facing the same issue?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's too late to answer that question , But I say to friends who may face this problem.

Any time You used to dataBinding and at unit test faced with *NoClassDefFoundError*

first add this lines in build.gradle(Module)

```
testOptions {
        unitTests{
            isIncludeAndroidResources=true
        }
    }
```

then add this library to the dependencies at build.gradle(Module)

```
kaptTest("androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:7.0.4")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a known issue which you can review [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37131426). I've been tracking this issue since February. Doesn't seem to be fixed yet.

Answer (score 0):

added `android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding=true` in `gradle.properties` . According to the name of this property, I think it could work for sometimes but not always, you can try.

Comment: @Ballem however, it could only works at beta or alpha version of android studio, you should care.